# panic: unable to bootstrap orderer. Error reading genesis block file: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am working on hyperledger blockchain. I am running 4 organizations network, I have developed docker-compose.yml file. When is start docker-compose all containers are starting but orderer.example.com container is not starting i.e., the container is exiting with code 2.

Below is the orderer.example.com docker-compose configuration details and logs of the orderer.example.com container.

docker-compose configuration details

```
###########################################
# Orderer Docker Container Config
###########################################
  orderer.example.com:
  container_name: orderer.example.com
  image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
  environment:
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
    - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
    - OERDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp

  working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer

  command: orderer

  ports:
  - 7050:7050 

  volumes:
    - ./channel-artifacts/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/OrdererPeer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1/peer0
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg2/peer0
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg3/peer0
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/peers/peer0.org4.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg4/peer0

  networks:
    - basic
```

Error logs of orderer.example.com container

```
2019-10-18 08:08:51.429 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 001 Kafka.Version unset, setting to 0.10.2.0
2019-10-18 08:08:51.556 UTC [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 002 Orderer config values:
    General.LedgerType = "file"
    General.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    General.ListenPort = 7050
    General.TLS.Enabled = false
    General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key"
    General.TLS.Certificate = "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt"
    General.TLS.RootCAs = [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt]
    General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    General.Cluster.ListenAddress = ""
    General.Cluster.ListenPort = 0
    General.Cluster.ServerCertificate = ""
    General.Cluster.ServerPrivateKey = ""
    General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = ""
    General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = ""
    General.Cluster.RootCAs = []
    General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
    General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBackgroundRefreshInterval = 5m0s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationMaxRetries = 12
    General.Cluster.SendBufferSize = 10
    General.Cluster.CertExpirationWarningThreshold = 168h0m0s
    General.Cluster.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
    General.ConnectionTimeout = 0s
    General.GenesisMethod = "file"
    General.GenesisProfile = "SampleInsecureSolo"
    General.SystemChannel = "test-system-channel-name"
    General.GenesisFile = "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock"
    General.Profile.Enabled = false
    General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
    General.LocalMSPDir = "/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp"
    General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
    General.BCCSP.ProviderName = "SW"
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.SecLevel = 256
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.HashFamily = "SHA2"
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.Ephemeral = false
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = "/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp/keystore"
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.DummyKeystore =
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.InmemKeystore =
    General.BCCSP.PluginOpts =
    General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
    General.Authentication.NoExpirationChecks = false
    FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
    FileLedger.Prefix = "hyperledger-fabric-ordererledger"
    RAMLedger.HistorySize = 1000
    Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 5s
    Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 10m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
    Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
    Kafka.Verbose = false
    Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
    Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
    Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Enabled = false
    Kafka.SASLPlain.User = ""
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Password = ""
    Kafka.Topic.ReplicationFactor = 3
    Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = ""
    Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
    Consensus = map[WALDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal SnapDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot]
    Operations.ListenAddress = "127.0.0.1:8443"
    Operations.TLS.Enabled = false
    Operations.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Operations.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Operations.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Operations.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Operations.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Metrics.Provider = "disabled"
    Metrics.Statsd.Network = "udp"
    Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
    Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
    Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
panic: unable to bootstrap orderer. Error reading genesis block file: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock: no such file or directory

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/bootstrap/file.(*fileBootstrapper).GenesisBlock(0xc0002bb2b0, 0xc0002bb2b0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/bootstrap/file/bootstrap.go:39 +0x1d0
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.extractBootstrapBlock(0xc000444900, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:532 +0x1bd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Start(0x1018e03, 0x5, 0xc000444900)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:96 +0x43
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:91 +0x1ce
main.main()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
```

When I got this error I made changes to the code follows as below:

```
environment:
  - OERDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesis.block
volumes:
  - ./channel-artifacts/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric
```

But the I got the same error below is the error logs:

```
2019-10-18 07:49:44.841 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> ERRO 001 failed to parse config:  Error reading configuration: Unsupported Config Type ""
```

Please help me with this issue. please ignore is there are any indentation error

Comment: Seems like genesis block is not present in channel-artifacts directory

Comment: @NarendranathReddy yes, genesis.block file is present, I have checked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its weird,

According to your yaml manifest

Supplied path is: 
`- OERDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block`

Error log stats:

```
Error reading genesis block file: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock: no such file or directory
```

> Something you are missing, please upload the configuration to github
>   so that I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

In your volume, you have to specify your path to block.genesis
And you have to give the same link in environment genesis file path
environment:
  - OERDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.pb
volumes:
  - ./channel-artifacts/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric
 - ./orderer/genesis_block.pb:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.pb

Answer (score 0):

Please check the genesis block path. Docker is not able to locate the file

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this issue by again generating the cryptography files in the folder  "channel-artifacts" and "crypto-config".

1)
[generating the cryptography files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGaMx.png)

2. By again Running Configtxgen to create artifacts

Answer (score -1):

OERDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE >> ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE